# Export button from blender to ogre is inactive

Tags: blender, ogre

I have downloaded a coconut tree mesh from internet. I tried to export the mesh from blender 2.66 to ogre. But the File->export->Ogre3d(.scene and .mesh) button is inactive. What can be reason for this button to be inactive? In such cases how can I export from blender to ogre?

Comment: Are you able to enable/reable the addon and does this cause any errors in the terminal window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be in object mode for the button to be selectable.